# is there any way to use the SIMILAR TO operator in SQL Server or any other operators like Similar TO operator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql, sql-delete

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME SIMILAR TO '%(_100|_200|_300)';
```

Above is a postgresql query.
Need an equivalent SQL Server query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want pattern matching against a regex. In SQL Server you could phrase this as:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%(_[123]00)';
```

This searches for strings that end with `'(_100)'` or `'(_200)'` or `'(_300)'`.

In am unsure that you really want the parentheses: these are *literals*, meaning that it will actually search for parentheses in the string. If that's not what you want, then remove them.

Comment: Pattern matching is fine. But, i need to execute the query which doesn't fit under ant pattern

Below is an example
COLUMN_NAME SIMILAR TO '%(_123|_2780|_379|_5936|_243755)';

In this case, POSTGRESQL's SIMILAR TO will work like multiple LIKE condition

Comment: @SairamRamesh: this won't work in SQL Server, that has very limited regex support. You would need multiple `LIKE` expessions.